# the difference between built-in authentication and custom authentication in oracle apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What is the difference between built-in authentication and custom authentication in oracle apex 5?
What are the limitation in using built-in authentication in apex 5?
What are the cons and pros built-in authentication and custom authentication?

Answer (score 7):

Built-in as in Apex authentication?

Since I am a senior Oracle programmer, I tend to always use **Custom** and program the authentication myself.

Apex has the following authentication schemes:

**1) Application Express Accounts**

** Pros - Easy to use (full interface with apex)

** Cons - Can't limit users between applications (within a workspace)

**2) Database Accounts**

** Pros - If you have an application that uses oracle schema for authentication, then this provides easy integration

** Cons - Database accounts

**3) Custom (most common)**

** Pros - Great if you are accessing a system with different front-ends or if 
you are extending a system that already has it's authentication scheme set-up.  IF you can code it in pl/sql or Java, you can authenticate.

** Cons - You need to code the whole user admin interface (if needed)

**4) HTTP Header Variable**

** Pros - Integrates easily if your network has a SSO server that sets a header variable by the web server

** Cons - Haven't found many use cases for this

**5) LDAP Directory**

** Pros - Great to simply use your companies LDAP for authentication

** Cons - I have found that it's more flexible to simply use custom authentication and `dbms_ldap` for Microsoft Active Directory.

**6) Open Door Credentials**

** No pros or cons. This is simply for testing. System asks you for a username and uses that username henceforth. (no password or checks)

**7) Oracle Application Server Single Sign-On**

** Pros - If your company uses Oracle's SSO server (E-business suite for example)  then this is for you.

** Cons - You need Oracle's SSO server :)

**8) No Authentication (Using DAD)**

** Pros - No login - Open website

** Cons - No login - Open website

Comment: if i use custom authentication , how to store user id in a session variable ?

Comment: You create an application item and set its value in the login function.

Comment: Nebras, no need, still use :APP_USER

Comment: re: cons in #1 - that's what authorisation schemes are for

Comment: @ScottWe In my experience, having an application item :USERID is more convenient then having :APP_USER (or username) and having to always retrieve the User id

Comment: Cons in #1. Authorization are for different level of access within the same application.  If I have a workspace with 3 schema access, that have 3-5 totally different applications.  I do not want users from Application1 being able to log into Application2. Handling that scenario with Authorization schemes is a very bad idea.

Comment: Olafur Tryggvason , Do you have tutorial about every things in apex 5 ? I find it difficult when i search about thing in apex . any possible help .

Comment: I've been using it since HTMLDB :) I have always found it an invaluable tool over the years.  

I really recommend that you go through Oracle's documentation.  It's really good and easy to read: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/index.htm

Comment: Olafur Tryggvason , Thanks .

Comment: I want to build application with two languages support , how a user can switch between them ?